# Why this program is having Segmentation fault (core dumped) in line 62: 13

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, combinations

Problem statement:

Given N sticks each of different integral length Li, find the probability that you can make a quadrilateral taking 4 sticks at random (not paying attention to the order) from the given N sticks. (Degenerate quadrilaterals not included.)

Constraints:

1 <= M<=10

3 <= N <= 1000

1 < = Li < = 1500

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int gcd(int n1,int n2)                                  // calculate GCD
    {
        if(n1==0||n2==0)    return 0;
        if(n1==n2)          return n1;
        if(n1>n2)           return gcd(n1-n2,n2);

        return gcd(n1,n2-n1);
    }



int main(void)
{
    int m;                                                  // test cases
    scanf("%d",&m);



    while(m--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[1501];
        int b[n];
        int i,val,k;

        for(i=1;i<=1500;i++) a[i]=0;                        //initialization

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)                                    //taking values
        {
            scanf("%d",&val);
            a[val]=1;
        }


        int j=0,l,tcase=0,fcase=0;           //truecase and falsecase
        for(i=1;i<=1500;i++)              //making another array of length n
        {
            if(a[i]==1) 
            {
                b[j]=i;
                j++;
            }
        }


        if(n<4) printf("0/1\n");

        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<=n-4;i++)
            {
                for(j=i+1;j<=n-3;j++)
                {
                    for(k=j+1;k<=n-2;k++)
                    {
                        for(l=k+1;l<=n-1;l++)
                        {
                            if((b[i]+b[j]+b[k])>b[l]) tcase++;
                            else 
                            {
                                fcase=fcase+(n-l);
                                l=n;
                            }
                        }                                  //line: 62
                    }
                }
            }


            int ttcase=tcase+fcase;                    //total possible cases
            int div=gcd(tcase,ttcase);                //to make a/b form
            if(div==0) printf("0/1\n");
            else
            {
                tcase=tcase/div;                       //to make a/b form
                ttcase=ttcase/div;                     //to make a/b form
                printf("%d/%d\n",tcase,ttcase);
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never check the result of `scanf()` that's a possible cause. Also, you have TOO MANY NESTED `for` loops, that's a design error, rethink your program.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&val);`: if val is too high it overflows. If val isn't an integer too...

Comment: Is this an online challenge question which you cannot solve for the example test case? Note: using recursion to compute GCD is overkill. It can be done quite simply with an inline `while` loop of just a few lines, with `while((z = x % y) != 0) { x = y; y = z; }` with inputs `x` and `y` and output `z`.

Comment: Aside: please avoid the use of `l` as a variable for the same reason not to use `O`. Single-letter variables are bad enough, but these make the code hard to read due to confusion with `1` and `0`, although the latter is distinguished in some monospace fonts.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi But same program is running well if I am not using else condition in the inner most loop

Comment: @Weather Vane  Thanks for GCD algorithm.

Comment: @sunny You will soon learn that "*running well*" has no absolute meaning when programming with c, you ignore the return value and that's a bug, period.